# What is valid for a find statement in Capybara?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

The following JQuery code

```
$(".batch_fund_fields:first input[name*='code']")
```

is valid when I'm using the JavaScript console. But if I do

```
find(".batch_fund_fields:first input[name*='code']")
```

within Capybara, I get the error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64)
from /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'
```

and even

```
find(".batch_fund_fields:first")
```

gives a similar error.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method doesn't give much information, and doing a google search using `capybara rails "find"` doesn't help much.

What's valid for a `find` statement in Capybara?

(I haven't added the HTML for the page, because it's saying the argument is invalid, not that it can't find any elements)

Comment: Is it because `:first` is jQuery but Capybara's only using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no valid CSS :first selector -- there is :first-child and :first-of-type  --  The allowed queries have to be valid CSS  - no jQuery extensions allowed.

If you really want the behavior of JQueries :first extension you could do

```
first(".batch_fund_fields", minimum: 1).find("input[name*='code']")
```